# Php, how to copy a table from a database and paste to another

Tags: php, sql, database

I need to retrieve a table and all his fields from a database A and after, i need to paste this table on an another database B.

Theses 2 tables are on the same server, and i need to do that from a PHP script on the server B.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have any DB administration tool installed, like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Can't you dump the table using mysqldump(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html?iframe=true&width=100)?

Comment: Yes, but i need to do that on a PHP script, automactly with a crontab for example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE db2.table LIKE db1.table;
INSERT INTO db2.table SELECT * FROM db1.table;
```

If you copy the whole table with data and structure (as you do) , you can even simplify this into one single command like this:

```
CREATE TABLE db1.table
    AS (SELECT * FROM db2.table);
```

Comment: Great! I did not know "CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ..." sentence

Comment: Me neither ^^ I test, thanks !

Comment: You are welcome. Check my update. It can be done even simpler. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3,... 
FROM srcTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM destTable 
                 WHERE (srcTable.Field1=destTable.Field1 and
                       SrcTable.Field2=DestTable.Field2...etc.)
                 )
```

Comment: lol, I really wonder why did this answer is downvoted :)

Comment: @RoyalBg I'm with you. Note that you can vote it up ;)

Answer (score 0):

With various PHP extensions:

```
*_query/execute('insert into table2 select * from table1');
```

inserting all select values